# Is there an R online compiler that enables to run code line by line?

Tags: r, line-by-line, online-compilation

I'm looking for an R online compiler, such as [myCompiler](https://www.mycompiler.io/new/r), that enables to run code line by line.
Like what one gets in RStudio when pressing the *Run* button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried RStudio cloud? https://rstudio.cloud/

Comment: You can also host RStudio yourself, where you are not limited by the free tier resource limits.

Comment: @mhovd Can you explain what you mean by "hosting Rstudio" ?

Comment: It seems like a nice tool, even if it is intended as a mean to teach R

Comment: @Julien, take a look at RStudio Server (https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/)

Comment: I am not on Linux, so RStudio Server won't run

Comment: @Julien , you absolutely can run it on Windows if you choose to :)  either through Docker - https://www.rocker-project.org/ - or Windows subsystem for Linux  - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049776974-Using-RStudio-Server-in-Windows-WSL2 .

Comment: Too much of a hassle for me, for the moment though :)

Answer (score 3):

Some Jupyter variants let you run a single line or a selection, Google Colab ( https://colab.to/r for new R Notebook ) or Kaggle ( https://www.kaggle.com/docs/notebooks ) for example, both use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Bit different take would perhaps be RStudio in Binder.
Example - http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/r/master?urlpath=rstudio
More details - https://github.com/binder-examples/r